# How can I highlight a cell with text based on if that text exists in cell in a separate row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a row of 200 text cells. This is a list of original names.

I then have samples of various numbers of names in another row. I would like to be able to highlight the names in this sample that are also found in the original list of rows. How can I do this with conditional formatting?

I have tried the search function but can't seem to get it to accept to find_within a row of text over multiple column. Thank you for any help.

Edit for clarification:

I am having problems highlighting cells in one row that match cells in another row. Both are text.

[here is an example: I would like Sample cell with curtis' name in it be highlighted conditionally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ki3fW.png)

here is an example: I would like Sample cell with curtis' name in it be highlighted conditionally because it is found in the names row

[Here is the error I get when I try to search for specific text within a range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4O6v.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well - thank you for letting me know. But any information on what is unclear would be helpful. See edit

Comment: Added image example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

[image]

In Conditional Formatting, create a new rule using a formula. Use the `COUNTIFS()` function; and then select the "Name" row (row 5) as the first parameter, and then choose the first VALUE in the "Sample" row as the second. Set the "Applies to" to be the entire width of the "Sample" row.

Comment: Thank you! This coupled with the TRIM() function did the trick. =COUNTIFS(1:1,TRIM(D2))

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($D$1:$O$1=A1)*1)>0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply googling, "excel conditional formatting based on another cell"?
There are some stumbling blocks when trying to do this, but since I can't see your formula you're using in the conditional formatting, it's impossible to determine exactly where you are having trouble.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes I have and results and most are about finding matching values rather than matching text. Or, for example, [this link](https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cell-text/) has a section "Excel Conditional Formatting Entire Row Based on One Cell Text" which I tried following, but it is the opposite I am looking to do. I am looking for formatting a row of single cells based on an entire row.